# jQuery: how do I insert html into a string, both before the string (the easy part) and WITHIN the string?

Tags: jquery, html

I have titles for blog posts that are formatted like this:

```
<h1 class="entry-title">category text...blog post title</h1>
```

(The '...' is actually an html entity `&#8230;`)

There are hundreds of them so going in and adding the html code by hand would take too long.

What I need to do is insert an span tag before the text, that's the easy part:

```
$('.entry-title').prepend('<span class="category">');
```

and insert the closing  tag before the '...'

So the result would be

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><span class="category">category text</span>...blog post title</h1>
```

So I need to find the substring '...' and prepend `</span>`

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: The entity is probably converted to the actual character, and as it's text, linebreaks and other stuff could mean there is more than one textnode, so you should pobably post the exact text you're trying to match ?

Comment: you can't insert a partial tag. When you prepend the opening span tag, it's automagically completed, making it a span element with no content. Why are you doing this client-side rather than updating the database, or in the application code(php for example) that generates the html? javascript/jquery just seems like the wrong tool for the job here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert the start tag at the same time as the end tag.

```
var index = $('.entry-title').html().indexOf('...');

$('.entry-title').html('<span class="category">' + $('.entry-title').html().substring(0, index) + '</span>' + $('.entry-title').html().substring(index));
```

Comment: Thanks! When I switched your '...' to the actual entity it worked.

Comment: Ah ok I'm running into a problem on the index page (this code is working on the single post page.) When I try to replicate it on the index page each blog post title is the same. Here is what I used: `$(function() {
 var dotdotdot = $('.entry-title').html().indexOf('…');
 $('.entry-title').html('<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="category">' + $('.entry-title').html().substring(0, dotdotdot) + '</span>' + $('.entry-title').html().substring(dotdotdot) + '</a>');
});` It has the addition of the link to the post on the index page. How do I modify this for a loop?

Comment: @semidivine From what it sounds, all blog posts have `<h1 class="entry-title>`, and you are updating all of the titles to the same html by using `$('.entry-title')`. You should loop through each. [Here is a jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jPG3n/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex

```
$('.entry-title').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.html(el.html().replace(/^(.*?)\…/, '<span class="category">$1</span>&#8230;'));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRdDP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

User below code snippet.

```
var title = $('title').text();
var titlePart = title.split("...");
var newTitle = "<span>" + titlePart[0] + "</span>" + titlePart[1];
$('title').text(newTitle);
```

Comment: In place of title you can use `.entry-title` as per your codes.